# Passing javascript array to coldfusion CFC via Json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, coldfusion

i use this javascript to capture all checkboxes checked in a flexigrid and try to send this array of row ids to an CFC

```
function removeCertidao(){
    var allVals = [];
    $("input[id='certidao']:checked").each(function() {
        allVals.push($(this).val());
    });
    if (allVals.length == 0) {
        alert('É necessário escolher ao menos uma certidão.');
        return false;
    } else {
        alert(allVals);
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "../../CFC/CRC.cfc",
        data: {
            method: "removeCertidaoCRC",
            numSeqCertidao: allVals,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(){
            alert('YES');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('NO');
        }
    });             
 }
```

CFC Below

```
<cffunction access="remote" name="removeCertidaoCRC" returntype="boolean">
    <cfargument name="numSeqCertidao" type="array" required="true">
<cftry>
    <cftransaction>
        <cfquery datasource="portalCompras">
        UPDATE CRC_CERTIDAO CC
           SET CC.ncdcrcstatus = 0
             WHERE CC.NCDCRCCERTIDAO in <cfqueryparam value="#numSeqCertidao#"
                                                          cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"
                                                          list="yes">
    </cfquery>
        </cftransaction>
    <cftransaction action="commit" />
    <cfreturn 0>
    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cftransaction action="rollback" />
        <cfreturn #cfcatch.message#>
        </cfcatch>
</cftry>
</cffunction>
```

when i try to run this function, my server answers that The NUMSEQCERTIDAO argument passed to the removeCertidaoCRC function is not of type array.

I'm running out of options on a delayed project in which i entered just recently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery will do a good job of sending the array separated like `numSeqCertidao[] = 'val1', numSeqCertidao[] = 'val2' ...` but ColdFusion handles this badly and does not take this and rebuild it as an array.

Your JavaScript is not *sending* data in JSON format, the dataType option is for the format of the response data. For your needs I would suggest you send `numSeqCertidao` as a list, give your CFC method's argument a type of string and leave the rest of it as is, should work fine.

Slightly amended code:

```
function removeCertidao(){
    var allVals = [];
    $("input[id='certidao']:checked").each(function() {
        allVals.push($(this).val());
    });
    if (allVals.length == 0) {
        alert('É necessário escolher ao menos uma certidão.');
        return false;
    } else {
        alert(allVals);
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "../../CFC/CRC.cfc",
        data: {
            method: "removeCertidaoCRC",
            numSeqCertidao: allVals.join(),
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(){
            alert('YES');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('NO');
        }
    });             
 }

<cffunction access="remote" name="removeCertidaoCRC" returntype="boolean">
    <cfargument name="numSeqCertidao" type="string" required="true">
<cftry>
    <cftransaction>
        <cfquery datasource="portalCompras">
        UPDATE CRC_CERTIDAO CC
           SET CC.ncdcrcstatus = 0
             WHERE CC.NCDCRCCERTIDAO in <cfqueryparam value="#numSeqCertidao#"
                                                          cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"
                                                          list="yes">
    </cfquery>
        </cftransaction>
    <cftransaction action="commit" />
    <cfreturn 0>
    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cftransaction action="rollback" />
        <cfreturn #cfcatch.message#>
        </cfcatch>
</cftry>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: This works flawlessly... but now the success/error functions in the ajax doesn't work... it always falls in error but the records are changed in database

Comment: Probably because you are expecting json, try removing the datatype parameter from the ajax call or change it to text/html

Comment: very subtle difference, I had to dump the code into beyond compare to see it. `.join(),` for the win which is also resolved the issue I was having (passing the JavaScript Array to a CFC.

Answer (score 0):

What you're passing to the CFC is a Javascript array.  It's not a ColdFusion array. So to the CFC it looks like a string.  Change type to "string", or "any", or just omit it completely.