# .ajax is not invoking a CFC file to post data

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfc

I am unable to get a jQuery .ajax call to post data to my CFC, not sure what I am missing. Tried many different corrections, nothing working.

```
$('.addItem').click(function(){

    //data from button clicked  

    var fType = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "api.cfc",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { method: "add", ID: fType }    
    });
)};
```

CFC

```
<cfcomponent >
      <cffunction name="add" access="remote " returntype="string">
      <cfargument name="ID" type="string" required="true" />

         <cfquery datasource="dev" name="formT">
            Insert into formMap (num, stuff)
            Values (1, #arguments.ID#)
         </cfquery>

  </cffunction>
 </cfcomponent>
```

Comment: What have you done to debug? Are you seeing an xhr request logged in firebox or console?

Comment: your add() method has returntype="string" defined, but does not return a string - this may throw an error. change it to returntype="void" if your method does not need to return anything.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add the method name to the URL:

```
$('.addItem').click(function(){ 


//data from button clicked   

var fType = $(this).attr('id'); 

$.ajax({ 
    type: "post", 
    url: "api.cfc?method=add", 
    dataType: 'json', 
    data: { ID: fType }      
)};
```

You also need to deserialize the json server side into an object/var to read the values.

```
<cfcomponent >     
      <cffunction name="add" access="remote " returntype="string">     
      <cfargument name="theJson" required="true" />     

        <cfset json = deserializeJson(theJson)> 

         <cfquery datasource="dev" name="formT">     
            Insert into formMap (num, stuff)     
            Values (1, #json.ID#)     
         </cfquery>     

  </cffunction>     
 </cfcomponent>
```

Comment: I have tried both having the method in the url and under data:, but neither works.

Comment: Have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999501/invoke-coldfusion-function-using-ajax

Comment: This should be so simple and not working. I am using Railo and wondering if it is something with where it is looking for CFC files. If I want to test just using CFM, do I just remove the component tags and change the url to .cfm?

Comment: Have a look at this example, the answer appears to be working correctly.  If it still doesn't work, you may have another issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644816/passing-javascript-array-to-coldfusion-cfc-via-json

Comment: add the error parameter error: function(data,status,error){
       alert(data+': '+status+': '+error);
      },into your ajax so it shows if your getting some type of error on send i.e. 'Unauthorized' etc.