# Javascript to Coldfusion, using variable in javascript to query in CF with

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

Can I use a string array in my javascript file, pass it to a coldfusion page and use the elements in the array as parameters to search by in a < cfquery > ?

**.js**

```
$.get("submit.cfm",{arr: obj}).done( function(data) {
    alert('The returned data is: ' + data);
});
```

**.cfm**

```
<cfparam name="tempArr" default = "" >

<cfset array = ArrayNew(6)>

<cfloop from="1" to="6" index="i">
     <cfset ArrayAppend(array, tempArr[i])>
</cfloop>
```

The code is incomplete, but how can I pass the values of **obj** (string array) from javascript to the variable **tempArr** in my coldfusion code

Comment: See [reference 1](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1887-Using-jQuery-To-Pass-Arrays-To-Remote-ColdFusion-Components.htm), [reference 2](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2010/3/23/Using-jQuery-to-post-an-array-to-a-ColdFusion-Component), [reference 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644816/passing-javascript-array-to-coldfusion-cfc-via-json) and [many, many more...](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&output=search&q=passing+javascript+array+to+coldfusion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to convert your array to JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), so you can pass it to the server via Ajax.  Then you would need to process the JSON into a server-side array structure.

See this article for more details...

[Convert array to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json)